# Apex Global Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am trying to write a test class for this but I keep getting 0 coverage.

```
global class Company_Global
{
    public static final List<organization> lstOrg  = [Select isSandbox from Organization];
    public static string Environment;

    public static string getEnvironment()
    {
        if(lstOrg[0].isSandbox == False){
            Environment = 'Production';
            return Environment;
        }else{
            Environment = UserInfo.getUserName().substringAfterLast('.').toUpperCase();
            return Environment;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Test Class

```
@isTest(seeAllData=true)
public class Company_Global_test
{
    public static final List<organization> lstOrg  = [Select isSandbox from Organization];
    public static string Environment;

    public static testmethod string getEnvironment()
    {
       if(lstOrg[0].isSandbox == False){
            Environment = 'Production';
            return Environment;
        }else{
            Environment = UserInfo.getUserName().substringAfterLast('.').toUpperCase();
            return Environment;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: You need to call -> Company_Global_test.getEnvironment(); then only the method can be covered.

Comment: Your test class is not really testing your `Company_Global` class. You need to invoke the methods in your `Company_Global` from the test class, but as of now you have just written the same code that you have in your class in the test class as well. Take a look at these resources to get started on how to write a unit test --  [What are Apex Unit Tests?](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_unit_tests.htm) & [Get Started with Apex Unit Tests](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_testing/units/apex_testing_intro)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of a test class is to *call* the code and verify its output. That means your test method should look like this:

```
@isTest static void testGetEnvironment() {
  String environment = Company_Global.getEnvironment();
  ...
```

However, to really get 100% coverage, you need to inject data into your test:

```
@isTest static void testGetEnvironment() {
  Organization prodBox = (Organization)JSON.deserialize('{"IsSandbox":false}', Organization.class),
    testBox = (Organization)JSON.deserialize('{"IsSandbox":true}', Organization.class);
  Company_Global.lstOrg[0] = prodBox;
  System.assertEquals('Production',Company_Global.getEnvironment());
  Company_Global.lstOrg[0] = testBox;
  System.assertEquals(UserInfo.getUserName().substringAfterLast('.').toUpperCase(),Company_Global.getEnvironment());
}
```

Comment: +1 to injecting data to avoid (seeAllData=true)...!!

Comment: @YsrShk SeeAllData isn't meaningful to this test; you can always query Organization. However, the field "IsSandbox" is locked, so you have to inject it via JSON deserialization. Also, it makes sure you will have 100% coverage no matter which org you're in.

Comment: Actually I did not know a way to avoid seeAllData for some instances, where we use the existing things. Hence I added it. Curious to know if it works for static resource and custom label.

Comment: I am not getting 100% coverage due to the asserEqual not handling 'Production" correctly so any thoughts?

Comment: @Daryn Yeah, I accidentally reversed the "true" and "false" values in the test data. Edited my answer to reflect how it should look. This is the reason why you should always use asserts, to catch errors like this.

Comment: Yeah I just noted that as well. I made the correction and all is good. Thanks so much.